# How to return deferred.resolve() from function in function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do i get deferre.resolve from a function?

my Controller calls this:

```
service.getData().then(function(response){ //myFunc deferred response});
```

in Service:

```
var _getData = function (){
  $http.get(url).success(function(response){
   deferred.resolve(_myFunc(response.Message)); // or just myFunc doesnt matter
  });

  return deferred.promise; //it returns in the end of the function
}
```

and myFunc has also:

```
$http.get(url).success(function(response){
 deferred.resolve(response); 
});

return deferred.promise; // also my Func is returning
```

so i need the deferred resolve of myFunc, which is called in another func which is called in my controller.. and display it there

**EDIT**
I have return deferred.promise **BUT** it returns ONLY the first promise of the SERVICE function not myFunc, and i need the promise of myFunc

**EDIT 2**

Look also at Carson Drake's answer, it isn't anti-pattern!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually reduce the two into one chained call if you want to simplify if.

```
var _getData = function(){
return $http.get(url).then(function(response1){
    return $http.get(response1.data);
}).then(function(response2){
    return response2;
});
```

**UPDATE**
[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/X9QeMX?p=preview)

Comment: Indeed, there is no use in wrapping promises around... promises as $http already returns a promise. See this [post](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return defer.promise from the service of factory(whatever you are using)

```
var _getData = function (){
 var deferred = $q.defer();
 $http.get(url).success(function(response){
   deferred.resolve(_myFunc(response.Message)); // or just myFunc doesnt matter
});
return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: trying @squiroid solutions.. like i said i have return deffered i edited.. :3